# Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate() is rendering Visualforce email template without custom header

Tags: email, email-template, apex-email-service, singleemailmessage

Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate() is rendering Visualforce email template without custom header.

I have a requirement to send an email with custom header. So created a visualforce email template with a custom header.
But when I send get the rendered Email template using renderStoredEmailTemplate(). It is not returning with custom header.

Visualforce email template

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Welcome" recipientType="Contact" relatedToType="Case">

<messaging:emailHeader name="customHeader">
        000000
</messaging:emailHeader>
    
<messaging:plainTextEmailBody >
Congratulations!
Sample Visualforce Email Template.
</messaging:plainTextEmailBody>

</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Email Code

```
List<EmailTemplate> emailTemplate = [SELECT Id, Body, TemplateType  FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = 'Welcome_Letter_VF'];
String templateId = emailTemplate[0].Id;
String emailfooter = 'Message from salesforce'; // sample text to append at the end of email body.
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage rmail = Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(templateId, null, null);
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage amail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
amail.setTargetObjectId(UserInfo.getUserId());
amail.saveAsActivity = false;
amail.setPlainTextBody(rmail.getPlainTextBody() + emailfooter); // I want to assign render content to the email. If I comment this line. custom header is coming fine. But why custom header is not coming when I use renderedemailtemplate
amail.setTemplateID(templateId);

//Send Email Now
Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {amail});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you can't change email body on the fly.
Try to use this solution
https://opfocus.com/blog/sending-emails-in-salesforce-to-non-contacts-using-apex/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/163197)